# Omniauth twitter callback page solution?

Tags: omniauth-twitter

when i try to use that link http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback

facing this error

def callback_phase # rubocop:disable MethodLength
fail(OmniAuth::NoSessionError, "Session Expired") if session["oauth"].nil?

```
    request_token = ::OAuth::RequestToken.new(consumer, session["oauth"][name.to_s].delete("request_token"), session["oauth"][name.to_s].delete("request_secret"))
```

Routes are cleared and integration done but still this error unable to load page how to solve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.